# Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is not launching on anaconda navigator

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, navigator

Every time I try to launch the notebook, I get the following notification:

/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
(base) Marias-MacBook-Air-2:~ abdullahasim$ /anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 5: 47494 Segmentation fault: 11  $DIR/jupyter-notebook
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

I am still learning how to code in Python, so I am not sure what to do. I tried to launch it through Terminal, but I get the following error: Segmentation fault: 11.